# Clearing a SQLite table before saving data in it

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-pcl

I'm using SQLite.net (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) in my Xamarin Forms project and trying to save a user's projects in the database.

In order to make sure there won't be any duplicates, I want to first clear the table by calling:

`await _db.DeleteAllAsync<Project>();`

This is throwing the following exception if I never saved any data in the database.

> SQLite.SQLiteException: 'no such table: Project'

I realize I can do this in a `try/catch` block but is there a way to clear a particular table before saving any data in it without getting exceptions in case no data has ever been saved in it before?

P.S.
I'm aware of the `await _db.InsertOrReplaceAsync(List<Project>)` but when I tried that I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'method arguments are incompatible'

I don't know what to make of this exception as it's pretty vague.

How do I make sure my table is clear before saving some data in it?

Comment: have you created the table first?  You could also query the table first to see if it returns any rows before attempting to clear it.  Your `InsertOrReplaceAsync` is failing because you're passing it a `List<Project>` instead of a single `Project`

Comment: How do I save multiple `Project`'s in a table?

Comment: Quick search indicates I have to serialize my data first. Is that the only way to do it?

Comment: use `InsertAll` or `InsertAllAsync`